# Can I get Route Locations Array (Coordinates) of a calculated route? (Skobbler Maps)

Tags: ios, objective-c, skmaps

In our app, we calculate a route based on an array of custom locations.
We get those locations from our server (But it's generated using Graphhopper).

We need those custom locations for two things:

1) To be able to fetch some POI data along the way

2) To calculate the same route in our iOS app as on our Web app

Now, it all works fine until the user makes a wrong turn and we need to start rerouting.
Rerouting itself is fine, but we still need to fetch fresh POI data, and we cannot do that without having our array of route locations.

So my question is - is there a way to get an array of route locations, once the rerouting is complete?
We need the same route locations array that we would put in this method:

```
[[SKRoutingService sharedInstance] calculateRouteWithSettings:settings customLocations:locationsArray];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand you question, you want to access the routeInformation for the route that was calculated in the rerouting call.

If this is the case - when a reroute call is triggered, once a new route is available you will receive a callback in [didFinishRouteCalculationWithInfo](http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/ios/2.5.0/Protocols/SKRoutingDelegate.html#//api/name/routingService:didFinishRouteCalculationWithInfo:) - the `calculatedAfterRerouting` flag in the SKRouteInformation argument will be set to true.

Based on this information you should be able to ask for the points on the route via the [routeCoordinatesForRouteWithId](http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/ios/2.5.0/Classes/SKRoutingService.html#//api/name/routeCoordinatesForRouteWithId:) method